# Restart jboss service or redoploy when modifying application configurations?

Tags: java, jboss, rhel, restart

When the properties or .xml of some application (ear) in jboss (RHEL) are modified, is it necessary to restart the jboss service or simply by doing a redeploy (mv .deployed .dodeploy) are the changes recognized?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to redeploy the application. Of course if you change the server configuration that's a different story.